# Ho to validate Fhir R4 Resource based on profiles and custom structure definition?

Tags: validation, resources, hl7-fhir

I am using Hl7.Fhir.Serialization and Hl7.Fhir.Validation to do resource specific validation as bellow. But this is a basic validation, I want to do profile specific validations and extension based validation in Fhir R4, can someone suggest me a better solution?

```
private Hl7.Fhir.Validation.Validator GetValidator()
{
   return new Hl7.Fhir.Validation.Validator(PrepareValidationSettings());
}

private ValidationSettings PrepareValidationSettings()
{
     var settings = ValidationSettings.CreateDefault();
     settings.EnableXsdValidation = false;
     settings.Trace = false;
     settings.ResourceResolver = this.ProfileSource;
     settings.SkipConstraintValidation = false;
     settings.ResolveExteralReferences = true;
     settings.GenerateSnapshot = false;
     settings.TerminologyService = this.TerminologySource;

     return settings;
}


public FhirResponse ValidateResource(Resource resource)
{
      var serializedResourceXml = FhirSerializer.SerializeResourceToXml(resource);
      var reader = SerializationUtil.XmlReaderFromXmlText(serializedResourceXml);

      var valdationResult = GetValidator().Validate(reader);  // Validate the resource 

      if (valdationResult.Errors == 0)
      {
          return new FhirResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      }

     return new FhirResponse(valdationResult, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've asked another question about validation previously, and Ewout pointed you to the demo project available: https://github.com/FirelyTeam/Furore.Fhir.ValidationDemo

If you inspect the code, you will find that you can add other resolvers to the settings.ResourceResolver, which in your case presumably only points to the base specification.

For example, look for this line:

```
var directorySource = new CachedResolver(new DirectorySource(profilePath, new DirectorySourceSettings { IncludeSubDirectories = true }));
```

It sets a resolver to the folder containing your custom profiles and extensions, and in the next line combines that with the base specification to be used in the validator settings.

Comment: in my project I am storing the specification.zip in one project and custom structure definitions are store in different project, here is my code sample, that didn't work
                        
var directorySource = new CachedResolver(new DirectorySource(profilePath, new DirectorySourceSettings { IncludeSubDirectories = true }));

var result = new MultiResolver(directorySource, validator.ZipResolver);

StructureDefinition pat =                        validator.ZipResolver.ResolveByCanonicalUri("http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/procedure-causedBy")    as StructureDefinition

Comment: It does not matter if your StructureDefinitions are stored in a different folder, as long as your application can access that. Could you explain what did not work, what errors you got? Because from that partial piece of code I cannot determine anything. And could you run the ValidationDemo to see if/how that works? Stepping through that and inspecting the values should give you a better understanding, which you can then use to debug your own application.